# Bash : Taking a wildcard as argument of a shell script and being able to expand it

Tags: bash, wildcard

I am faced to a specific issue which is at first sight easy.

If I type on my bash shell the wildcard corresponding to different files :

```
$ myfile=probe_*.txt
```

and do after :

```
$ echo $myfile
```

I get the list of all files matching the wildcard, i.e :

```
$ probe_GCph.txt probe_GCsp.txt probe_GCsp_WL_GCph.txt probe_GCsp_XC.txt probe_GCsp_XC_WL_GCph.txt probe_WL.tx
```

But now, I would like to make the wildcard `probe_*.txt`as the argument `$2` into a function.

For  the moment, If I do in a bash function :

```
function multiple_files { myfile=$2
                          echo $1
                          echo $3
                          echo $myfile
                        }
```

Then, at the following execution :

`$ multiple_files . $myfile dir/`

Then I get only the first filename `probe_GCph.txt` which is printed for the third echo (`echo $myfile`) in the definition of the bash function.

How can I pass a wildcard name of files as argument (here $2) and be able after to expand it to list all the filenames corresponding in a bash function ?

There seems to be a conflict between the argument $2 which takes only into account the first expanded files which is `probe_GCph.txt` and the passing of a wildcard as argument $2 without expanding it.

How to circumvent this issue ?

Comment: Quote your wildcard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your function to accept multiple arguments instead of just one. This is how most other tools work (cp/mv/ls/grep/sed to name a few):

```
multiple_files() {
  first="$1"
  last="${@: -1}"
  files=( "${@:2:$#-2}" )

  echo "The first thing was $first"
  echo "The last  thing was $last"
  for file in "${files[@]}"
  do
    echo "One of the files is $file"
  done
}

multiple_files . probe_*.txt dir/
```

This results in:

```
The first thing was .
The last  thing was dir/
One of the files is probe_GCph.txt
One of the files is probe_GCsp.txt
One of the files is probe_GCsp_WL_GCph.txt
One of the files is probe_GCsp_XC.txt
```

If you actually need the pattern itself, or if you want to accept multiple patterns and keep them separate, you'll probably need to quote the glob as described in the other answers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my example as posted in original question, this works perfectly. Unfortunately, this doesn't work with the following command : `multiple_files dir1/ *.f90 dir2/` and I don't understand why ? Could explain please what does `last="${@: -1}"` and `files=( "${@:2:$#-2}" )` in your solution above ? I think my  error comes from these 2 instructions. Regards

Comment: These use array slicing to get the last argument, and the second through penultimate elements. What's the output of this function when you run it like that?

Comment: The command `multiple_files  temp_sources/ *.f90 dir2/`returns `The first thing was temp_sources/`, `The last  thing was dir2/`and `One of the files is *.f90`: could you see what's wrong ? Regards

Comment: This means you have no files matching `*.f90` in the current directory

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes avoid expanding shell glob, but still allow for shell variable replacement.  It's worth while to note that single quotes both prevent glob (or wildcard like expansions) and variable interpolations.

TL;DR:

Call your function this way:

```
multiple_files . "$myfile" dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass wildcard inside the function you'll need either escape the special character or include the wildcard sequence in quotes.

```
$ ls
f1  f2  f3

$ function multiple_files { myfile=$2; echo $1; echo $2; echo $myfile;}
$ multiple_files '*' f\*
f1 f2 f3
f1 f2 f3
f1 f2 f3
```

If you don't escape the wildcard it's expanded prior calling the function

```
$ multiple_files f*
f1
f2
f2
```

To print the wildcard inside the function you'll need to include variable in quotes too. There are some tricks with `eval` too:

```
$ function multiple_files { myfile=$2; echo $1; eval echo "$2"; echo "$2"; echo "$myfile"; eval echo "$myfile";}
$ multiple_files '*' f\*
f1 f2 f3
f1 f2 f3
f*
f*
f1 f2 f3
```

Comment: See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete re: legacy ksh function declaration syntax (particularly the entry in the last table).

Comment: ...and re: suggested use of `eval` to perform glob expansion, one can just leave off the quotes on a parameter expansion (possibly with `IFS` cleared to avoid string-splitting) to perform globbing, *without* having a `$(rm -rf ~)` substring in your data treated as a command. [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) is pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very, very simple solution to this. In your script, put the argument to be expanded in quotes when reassigning it...

```
#!/bin/bash
list="$1"
for i in $list ; do echo $i ; done
```

...save this as myscript.sh and make it executable. Then when you call the script, put the pattern containing wildcards that you wish to pass in quotes as well - lets say you want a list of all the text files in the directory...

```
./myscript "*.txt"
```

...as you can see, the first argument should now become a list of items, and any additional arguments you pass to the script can be referenced in the normal fashion ($2, $3, $4, etc)